# OAuth2::Error Google +

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, google-plus

[My code in omniauth.rb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HINtV.png) I'm using Rails with OAuth so users can sign in with Google +

I've registered my app on the dev site, got my credentials, and listed my origin and callback as: http://localhost:3000 and that with /auth/google/callback on the end respectively.

However, when I navigate to Google + to authenticate, I click 'allow' and I'm navigated back to my app, I receive this Rails error message:

OAuth2::Error
redirect_uri_mismatch: { "error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch" }

I don't understand how to fix this. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can not set localhost directly as your callback. You can use 127.0.0.1:3000/auth/google/callback instead as your callback url and it should work.

Comment: this did not work. Now I'm getting a 400 error from Google instead of a Rails error

Comment: I had missed the port. Can you try the editted answer. Basically replace localhost with 127.0.0.1